# Angle between two orientations

Tags: ros, pose, ros-kinetic, quaternion, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two orientations given, as intrinsic yaw-roll-pitch (rzyx).

How to calculate the angle between the "Z" axes of them?

Converting the orientations to quaternions or to anything else is allowed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301988/angle-between-two-orientations/) by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-08-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-29**:
Does #q10124 not answer this? See also [tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions).

**Comment by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on 2018-08-29**:
Looks like it's the finding of the full rotation between orientations.
What I need, it the **single** angle between the Z axes of orientations.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-08-29**:
I'd look into the axis angle representation.
Alternatively, what you're describing could be interpreted as angular *distance* which you can formulate the same way you might an L2 distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest converting both of the orientations into transformation objects, then create a point object 1m along the Z axis. Then use the two transformations to transform the point from the frame of one transform into the other. This will give you two unit vectors one if which is (0 0 1)^ the other which is something else, you can then use the dot product to find the angle between the two.

In a little bit more detail you'd create the two transform objects like this.

```
tf2::Quaternion q1;
q1.setRPY(roll, pitch, yaw); // node the order
tf2::Transform t1(q1);
```

Do the same with q2 and t2 for the other orientation then create the Z axis unit point.

```
tf2::Vector3 zPoint(0,0,1);
```

Transform it from one frame to the other.

```
tf2::Vector3 otherZPoint = t1.inverseTimes(t2) * zPoint;
```

Now you can calculate the angle between the two unit vectors zPoint and otherZPoint as so.

```
float angle = acos(zPoint.dot(otherZPoint) );
```

It's a bit long winded but I hope this solves the problem you're asking about!

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on 2018-08-30**:
Yes, I think this is a working variant!

Isn't there an easier solution, without converting to transforms?
I was given this formula: math.atan(math.hypot(math.tan(pitch), math.tan(roll))), it almost works, but doesn't give values more than 90 degrees (when Z axes are "upside down" to each other).

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-30**:
I'm sure it could be simplified, the question is do you need to? Is performance critical for this calculation? If not and you've got a working solution then I'd say the job's done.